# Sorting Date and Time

Tags: c#

Am trying to write a console application to sort my date and time by ascending order based on start date, here is an example of I'm trying to do.

My input:

```
break Start1 = 15/02/12 12.30PM
break End1= 15/02/12 01.30PM
break Start2 = 15/02/12 11.00AM
break End2= 15/02/12 12.00PM
break Start3 = 15/02/12 12.00PM
break End3= 15/02/12 01.00PM
```

Am expecting my output should be like:

```
break Start1 = 15/02/12 11.00AM
break End1= 15/02/12 12.00PM
break Start2 = 15/02/12 12.00PM
break End2= 15/02/12 01.00PM
break Start3 = 15/02/12 12.30PM
break End3= 15/02/12 01.30PM
```

Please suggest me the best approach to solve this?

Comment: Can you store the corresponding Start and End date/times in a hashtable or similar structure to maintain the relationship between them?

Comment: If you have a new question based on answers you receive, please do _not_ edit your question with a brand new one. This has the effect of disconnecting the answers from their original context, and means that they make no sense in relation to the new question. If you have a supplementary question, it is best to ask a new question, as you have now done - thanks.

Comment: For ref, the OP's [supplementary question is here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15101915/how-to-add-date-objects-to-c-sharp-lists).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*I suggest that you want to pair original start and end values, and then order it only by start date.*

First you will have to pair the `Start` and `End`. E.g. with class:

```
public class Break
{
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
}
```

And then, when you populate a collection of such objects, just order it by `Start` with LINQ.

```
var breaks = new List<Break>()
                 {
                     new Break()
                         {
                             Start = new DateTime(2012,2,15,12,30,0),
                             End = new DateTime(2012,2,15,13,30,0)
                             ... /// etc.
                         }
                 };

var ordered = breaks.OrderBy(s => s.Start);
foreach (var ord in ordered)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(ord.Start);
    System.Console.WriteLine(ord.End);
}
```

**EDIT**

*To create paired datetimes objects you can use method like:*

```
public static Break ConvertToBreak(string startDate, string endDate, object gmtOffset)
{
     var dtStart = UnixTimeConverter(startDate, System.Convert.ToDecimal(gmtOffset));
     var dtEnd =  UnixTimeConverter(endDate, System.Convert.ToDecimal(gmtOffset));
     return new Break{Start = dtStart, End = dtEnd};
}
```

Comment: This is the only solution that pairs the Start and End times together (as of right now).  All the other solutions treat the datetimes as 6 separate items.

Answer (score 1):

you can put all your DateTimes in an array or in a List and use the standard methods to sort the arrays or lists, see here for an example: http://www.csharp-examples.net/sort-array

in .NET the [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) implements the `IComparable` interface so it is very easy to compare/sort these kind of variables.

said so, you could have two arrays or a matrix and sort each of them separately since from your example it looks like you take one value from start column and one value from en column etc...

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you just want to sort date/time objects. Since the code you posted is not C#, I'll make some assumptions.

First: let's assume you have your date/time combination in a [`DateTime` object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx). And I'll assume you have a list of them.

```
List<DateTime> dateTimes = new List<DateTime>();
dateTimes.AddRange(new []
{
    new DateTime(2012, 02, 15, 12, 30, 00),  // 15/02/12 12.30PM
    new DateTime(2012, 02, 15, 13, 30, 00),  // 15/02/12 01.30PM
    new DateTime(2012, 02, 15, 11, 00, 00),  // 15/02/12 11.00AM
    new DateTime(2012, 02, 15, 12, 00, 00),  // 15/02/12 12.00PM
    new DateTime(2012, 02, 15, 12, 00, 00),  // 15/02/12 12.00PM
    new DateTime(2012, 02, 15, 01, 00, 00),  // 15/02/12 01.00PM
});
```

You can sort them in-place like this:

```
dateTimes.Sort();
```

---

Or otherwise, if you have an array or any `IEnumerable<T>` in general, you can get a new enumerable sequence that is ordered:

```
IEnumerable<DateTime> dateTimes = new []
{
    new DateTime(2012, 02, 15, 12, 30, 00),  // 15/02/12 12.30PM
    new DateTime(2012, 02, 15, 13, 30, 00),  // 15/02/12 01.30PM
    new DateTime(2012, 02, 15, 11, 00, 00),  // 15/02/12 11.00AM
    new DateTime(2012, 02, 15, 12, 00, 00),  // 15/02/12 12.00PM
    new DateTime(2012, 02, 15, 12, 00, 00),  // 15/02/12 12.00PM
    new DateTime(2012, 02, 15, 01, 00, 00),  // 15/02/12 01.00PM
};

var orderedDateTimes = dateTimes.OrderBy(dt => dt);
```

Comment: I don't think this will do what he wants, because the start and end DateTime values need to be paired.  You should be sorting 3 items instead of 6.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I'd do it

I have no clue what specific requirements you have regarding how they are being sent in or if the end time is always 1 hour past the start time, this example simple shows how to sort them accordingly.

```
//GetYourInputValues() refers to however you plans on pulling in these inputs.
//It wasn't made clear in your post how you planned to do that.
string[] inputValues = GetYourInputValues(); 

//List that we will build, then sort, then print out.
List<DateTime> sortedDateTime = new List<DateTime>();

//Parse them into DateTime variables
foreach(var input in inputValues)
{
    DateTime inputDate;
    if(DateTime.TryParse(input, inputDate))
        sortedDateTime.Add(inputDate);
}
//Sort them ascending (for descending, flip a and b values)
sortedDateTime.Sort((a, b) => a.CompareTo(b));

//Print out the newly sorted values to console.
foreach(DateTime dt in sortedDateTime)
{
    Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("MM/dd/yy hh:mm:ss tt")):
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** If you are supposed to treat each Start/End as a pair (so that they are always together), then you'll have to do some minor changes (see @mipe34 answer). Otherwise, here is a full working example of how to do it:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    string text = 
  @"break Start1 = 15/02/12 12.30PM
    break End1= 15/02/12 01.30PM
    break Start2 = 15/02/12 11.00AM
    break End2= 15/02/12 12.00PM
    break Start3 = 15/02/12 12.00PM
    break End3= 15/02/12 01.00PM";

    string[] splitted = text.Split(new string[] {"\n", "\r"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    IList<DateTime> starts = new List<DateTime>();
    IList<DateTime> ends = new List<DateTime>();
    for (int i = 0; i < splitted.Length; i++) {
        string line = splitted[i].Trim();
        string date = line.Split('=')[1].Trim();
        DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd/MM/yy hh.mmtt", null);
        if (line.StartsWith("break Start")) {
            starts.Add(d);
        }
        else {
            ends.Add(d);
        }
    }

    starts = starts.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
    ends = ends.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();

    for (int i = 0; i < starts.Count; i++) {
        Console.WriteLine("break Start{0} = {1}", i + 1, starts[i].ToString("dd/MM/yy hh.mmtt"));
        Console.WriteLine("break End{0} = {1}", i + 1, ends[i].ToString("dd/MM/yy hh.mmtt"));
    }

}
```