# How to add date objects to C# lists?

Tags: c#

Earlier I had posted the question [Sorting Date and Time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15100233/146622).
It was answered by *mipe34*, but I am stuck trying to use the solution inside my code.

Here's that I did so far. I created a class as follows:

```
public class Meals
{
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
}
```

In my main class I have the following method that has date pair values:

```
 IList<DateTime> starts = new List<DateTime>();
            IList<DateTime> ends = new List<DateTime>();
            DateTime breakStart1 = new DateTime(2012, 02, 15, 12, 30, 00);  // 15/02/12 12.30PM
            DateTime breakEnd1 = new DateTime(2012, 02, 15, 13, 30, 00);  // 15/02/12 01.30PM
            DateTime breakStart2 = new DateTime(2012, 02, 15, 11, 00, 00);  // 15/02/12 11.00AM
            DateTime breakEnd2 = new DateTime(2012, 02, 15, 12, 00, 00);  // 15/02/12 12.00PM
            DateTime breakStart3 = new DateTime(2012, 02, 15, 12, 00, 00);  // 15/02/12 12.00PM
            DateTime breakEnd3 = new DateTime(2012, 02, 15, 01, 00, 00);  // 15/02/12 01.00PM
            starts.Add(breakStart1);
            starts.Add(breakStart2);
            starts.Add(breakStart3);
            ends.Add(breakEnd1);
            ends.Add(breakEnd2);
            ends.Add(breakEnd3);
            for (int i = 0; i < starts.Count; i++)
            {
                var breaks = new List<Break>()


             {
                 //for (int j= 0; j<starts.Count; j++)
                 //{
                 new Break()
                     {
                         MealStart = starts[i],
                         MealEnd = ends[i]

                     }
                // }
             };

                var ordered = breaks.OrderBy(s => s.MealStart);
                foreach (var ord in ordered)
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine(ord.MealStart);
                    System.Console.WriteLine(ord.MealEnd);
                }
            }
```

How can I pass all my date pairs and use his solution? it doesn't bring back the expected value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by creating objects and adding them to a list. You can use the collection initializer in this case.

```
var mealList = new List<Meals>
{
     new Meals { Start = dtmealStart1, End = dtmealStart1 },
     /* Repeat for the rest of them possibly incorporating some kind of loop to generate this list */
};

//and then get your sorted list
var sortedMealList = mealList.OrderBy(m => m.Start);
```

Comment: ,thanks for your help, i can't able to add a loop .updated my code above ,i think am screwed up.