# Sort Date time only by start date

Tags: c#

I have already asked a different question regarding [Sorting Date Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15100233/sorting-date-and-time) and got help from another user to pass my values. I am using a for loop like below, but definitely am wrong here because the code brings the value one by one rather than sorting.

```
public class Break
{
    public DateTime MealStart { get; set; }
    public DateTime MealEnd { get; set; }
}
```

my main class

```
IList<DateTime> starts = new List<DateTime>();
IList<DateTime> ends = new List<DateTime>();
DateTime breakStart1 = new DateTime(2012, 02, 15, 12, 30, 00);  // 15/02/12 12.30PM
DateTime breakEnd1 = new DateTime(2012, 02, 15, 13, 30, 00);  // 15/02/12 01.30PM
DateTime breakStart2 = new DateTime(2012, 02, 15, 11, 00, 00);  // 15/02/12 11.00AM
DateTime breakEnd2 = new DateTime(2012, 02, 15, 12, 00, 00);  // 15/02/12 12.00PM
DateTime breakStart3 = new DateTime(2012, 02, 15, 12, 00, 00);  // 15/02/12 12.00PM
DateTime breakEnd3 = new DateTime(2012, 02, 15, 01, 00, 00);  // 15/02/12 01.00PM
starts.Add(breakStart1);
starts.Add(breakStart2);
starts.Add(breakStart3);
ends.Add(breakEnd1);
ends.Add(breakEnd2);
ends.Add(breakEnd3);
for (int i = 0; i < starts.Count; i++)
{
    var breaks = new List<Break>()
    {
        //for (int j= 0; j<starts.Count; j++)
        //{
        new Break()
        {
            MealStart = starts[i],
            MealEnd = ends[i]

        }
        // }
    };

    var ordered = breaks.OrderBy(s => s.MealStart);
    foreach (var ord in ordered)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(ord.MealStart);
        System.Console.WriteLine(ord.MealEnd);
    }
}
```

I am expecting a result like below

```
breakStart1 = 15/02/12 11.00AM
breakEnd1= 15/02/12 12.00PM
breakStart2 = 15/02/12 12.00PM
breakEnd2= 15/02/12 01.00PM
breakStart3 = 15/02/12 12.30PM
breakEnd3= 15/02/12 01.30PM
```

but it's not because of the for loop.

Comment: I didn't -1 that cause I think it might create a chain reaction that might end with you having negetive reputation. dude, what are you trying to do exactly? (EXACTLY!)

Comment: @G.Y, Am exactly trying to do what Corylulu posted the answer,thanks to all

Comment: @Usher The edited question doesn't deserve the downvotes, he does display code examples and explains his issue (and fixed the broken English he posted before :P). So I will upvote you to counter your negative downvotes.

Comment: @Corylulu - this is quite downvoteable. An [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15100233/sorting-date-and-time) was asked, a [second one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15101915/how-to-add-date-objects-to-c-sharp-lists) was asked on a supplementary topic (that's fine), and now this has been asked that duplicates the second (not good). I've already had to revert a turn-one-question-into-another on the first one (not good).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add date objects to C# lists?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15101915/how-to-add-date-objects-to-c-sharp-lists)

Comment: @halfer, i colsed the duplicate .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating `breaks` after ever loop, you need to do this outside of the loop like this:

```
IList<DateTime> starts = new List<DateTime>();
IList<DateTime> ends = new List<DateTime>();
DateTime breakStart1 = new DateTime(2012, 02, 15, 12, 30, 00);  // 15/02/12 12.30PM
DateTime breakEnd1 = new DateTime(2012, 02, 15, 13, 30, 00);  // 15/02/12 01.30PM
DateTime breakStart2 = new DateTime(2012, 02, 15, 11, 00, 00);  // 15/02/12 11.00AM
DateTime breakEnd2 = new DateTime(2012, 02, 15, 12, 00, 00);  // 15/02/12 12.00PM
DateTime breakStart3 = new DateTime(2012, 02, 15, 12, 00, 00);  // 15/02/12 12.00PM
DateTime breakEnd3 = new DateTime(2012, 02, 15, 01, 00, 00);  // 15/02/12 01.00PM
starts.Add(breakStart1);
starts.Add(breakStart2);
starts.Add(breakStart3);
ends.Add(breakEnd1);
ends.Add(breakEnd2);
ends.Add(breakEnd3);
List<Break> breaks = new List<Break>();
for (int i = 0; i < starts.Count; i++)
{
    breaks.Add(new Break()
    {
        MealStart = starts[i],
        MealEnd = ends[i]
    });
}
var ordered = breaks.OrderBy(s => s.MealStart);
foreach (var ord in ordered)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(ord.MealStart);
    System.Console.WriteLine(ord.MealEnd);
}
```

Comment: @Usher No problem. Just remember to be clear and to the point here. Provide all the code you can in its simplest, most isolated form (preferably something testable). And always remember to select best answer :P

Comment: @Corylulu, i was trying to choose yours as best answer 5 mins before but its not let me to do it,so i have to wait until now to choose :)

Answer (score 2):

Since @Corylulu beat me to the punch on the basic issue, here's a different method that is slightly shorter:

```
IEnumerable<Break> breaks = 
    starts.Zip(ends, (s, e) => new Break { MealStart = s, MealEnd = e })
    .OrderBy(b => b.MealStart);

foreach (Break brk in breaks)
    Console.WriteLine("Start: {0}\tEnd: {1}", brk.BreakStart, brk.BreakEnd);
```

The `IEnumerable.Zip` method takes a pair of `IEnumerable`s and a transform function and produces an output `IEnumerable` containing the results of calling the transform function with members of each input `IEnumerable`.  You could convert it to a `List<Break>` with a `ToList()` at the end of course.